# Android Firebase Crashlytics NDK backtraces are missing line number for AAR dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics, firebase-console

I'm writing a native library with C++ and following the instruction [Get Android NDK crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports).

In my Android library project, I create new module for library called "recav" and add it as dependency to module "app". After test crash forcing with native NPE, the Firebase console show up a crash like below image:

[Crash for recav module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iyz4.png)

The crash is collected with file name, crash function and line number. It looks very nice.

After that, I build AAR file from module "recav" and import it to another Android project (Also follow the instruction from abow link). With the same test crash, the Firebase console show up crash like below image:

[Crash for recav.aar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs00C.png)

The crash now is colledted without file name and line number. It's difficult to determine the cause of the crash.

Why the result of crash from AAR dependency is poor information than from module one? What should I do to achieve the first result with AAR library?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably need to file a bug.

Comment: This could be related to the symbol files. Does the AAR file contain all the symbol files? As these getting uploaded for the other project?